# Button post HTML

Tags: javascript, html, postdata

I need to use a button without using a form. How do I make it send post data to the browser?

I am using:

```
<button style="height: 100px; width: 300px" onClick="parent.location='form1.php'" >Fill survey</button>
```

Comment: So how will the server find the data if you have no form?

Comment: the closest I would think is ajax, but it is still using get, not post

Comment: @C_Rance: POST can be used for AJAX-requests.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You'll need to create a form in JavaScript, then submit it. Look at this code

The HTML

```
<button type="button" onclick="proceed();">do</button>
```

The JavaScript code

```
function proceed () {
    var form = document.createElement('form');
    form.setAttribute('method', 'post');
    form.setAttribute('action', 'http://google.com');
    form.style.display = 'hidden';
    document.body.appendChild(form)
    form.submit();
}
```

Comment: one question more... how do i set what i want to post since im not getting anything input...

Comment: By either appending "?key1=value1&key2=value2" to the action value. Or by appending hidden input fields to the form.

Comment: Here's how to add a hidden input field, for anyone that is unsure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000795/create-a-hidden-field-in-javascript