# Forward GET parameter to next URL

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a form with HTML consisting of multiple pages, one per question (due to layout reasons). I use the 'GET' method to pass the parameters of the form input to next page, like this:

```
<form action="example.html" method="GET">
    <input type="number" step="0.1" name="Machine" id="Machine" placeholder="Machine">
    <input type="image" value="Submit" src="images/button.svg" alt="Forward"/>
</form>
```

This works fine and leads me to the URL

```
/example1.html?Machine=Input
```

On the next page, I use the same code as mentioned above (only different name and id for the input), but when I submit that page the parameters from the first page won't be redirected (of course). So the URL looks somewhat like this:

```
/example2.html?Amount=Input
```

I would need to have the parameters of the first page, too though. Basically looking like this

```
/example2.html?Machine=Input&Amount=Input
```

Is there a simple way for doing this with little Javascript or even without it? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click **Run code snippet** below to see a working example.

Instead of passing your results and going to the next step, you can just hide and reveal portions (steps) of the form using JavaScript.

A framework like AngularJS would make this extremely simple to do using declarative directive. But a plain old JavaScript will suffice.

The other advantage to this approach is that you can then POST your form to the web server.

```js
function goTo(step) {
  
  var steps = document.querySelectorAll('[step]'),
      formStep,
      formStepNo,
      i;
  
  for (i = 0; i < steps.length; i++) {
   
    formStep = steps[i];
    
    formStepNo = formStep.getAttribute('step');
    
    if (step == formStepNo) {
      formStep.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      formStep.style.display = 'none';  
    }
  }
}

var step = 1;
goTo(step);

function nextStep() {
  step++;
  goTo(step);
}

function backStep() {
  step--;
  goTo(step);
}
```

```html
<form action="example.html" method="POST">
    <div step="1">
      <p>Step 1</p>
      <input type="number" name="Machine" id="Machine" placeholder="Machine" />
      <button onclick="nextStep()" type="button">Forward</button>
    </div>
    <div step="2">
      <p>Step 2</p>
      <input type="string" name="foo" placeholder="foo"/> 
      <button type="button" onclick="backStep()">Back</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="nextStep()">Forward</button>
    </div>
    <div step="3">
      <p>Step 3</p>
      <input type="string" name="bar" placeholder="bar"/> 
      <button type="button" onclick="backStep()">Back</button>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Wow! Works like a charm and is a lot faster than reloading every page. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You could try adding hidden `input` elements to your form dynamically with javascript, created with `name` and `value` pairs from the GET parameters in `document.location.search`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this bit to get the parameters
[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

then this bit to add in the hidden form fields to the the form to pass along on the next submit

[Create a hidden field in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000795/create-a-hidden-field-in-javascript)

so something like this

```js
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var Amount= getParameterByName('Amount'); 
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
input.setAttribute("name", "Amount");
input.setAttribute("value", Amount);
document.getElementById("example2").appendChild(input);
```

```html
<form action="example1.html" method="GET" id="example1">
    <input type="number" step="0.1" name="Amount" id="Amount" placeholder="Amount">
    <input type="image" value="Submit" src="images/button.svg" alt="Forward"/>
</form>

<form action="example2.html" method="GET" id="example2">
    <input type="number" step="0.1" name="Machine" id="Machine" placeholder="Machine">
    <input type="image" value="Submit" src="images/button.svg" alt="Forward"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The code works fine, though I felt Martin pointed out a slightly faster alternative for my particular situation