# Create a hidden field, add it to form elements being sent on form submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem I can't seem to get a clear answer on.

Would like to create a hidden field just before submit (after submit button is clicked)(using onSumit()). In this field, I would like to give it a name and include a value and then, include the field with the other fields on their way out.

Is this possible? And if so, how can I get it to work? Thanx.

Comment: Absolutely.  This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1000811/571723

Comment: Also this for handling the form in JS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384712/capture-a-form-submit-in-javascript