# MySQL storing data in the database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, number-formatting

I am seeing a currency symbol `Â` when I store my data into a MySQL table, I have tried `trim()`, but still the `Â` has not been removed.

**JavaScript:**

```
var numZAR=new Intl.NumberFormat("en-ZAR",{    
    style:"currency",
    currency:"ZAR",
});

var total_raw = numZAR.format(Number(final_item_total).toFixed(2));

var total_string=total_raw.toString();

var total_show = total_string;
$('#final_total_amt').text(total_show);

$('#me').val(total_show); //displaying on front end textbox
```

**PHP code before the MySQL statement:**

```
$final = $_POST["me"];

$final = trim($final,"ZAR ");
```

This is what shows in the table: `Â 2,212.00`

Please help!
[image]

Comment: first see why `Â` is saving into db column. change column `collation to` `float` to prevent it. also use `parseFloat()` in your jQuery code too

Comment: Hi, I think there was a missing parentheses in the first line of code, which I tried to fix. Please review all your code very carefully that there are no other mistakes. For a solution, I would be inclined to store a [hidden field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1000811/673991) that just has the number with no currency symbol. And then in PHP store that in the MySQL table, no trim necessary.

Comment: Hey, 'final_item_total' is a float variable, changing _column collation to float_ is giving me 0 value in my colum

Answer (score 1):

`trim()` is used for removing specific characters at the beginning and end of the string. whilst `ltrim()` is used for removing at only the beginning, and finally `rtrim()` for removing at only the end.

You can lookup its prototype [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php).

Because it seems like you are using it incorrectly.

Let `$chars` be the string containing individual characters that you want to remove from the beginning and end of the string. Then you would have:

```
$chars = 'Â';
$final = $_POST["me"];
$final = trim($final, $chars);
```

`$final` would have the value of

> 2,212.00

Because `'Â'` would have been removed from the beginning.

Now as for where `'Â'` comes from, its most probably caused by the `Intl.NumberFormat` converter. If all your backend needs is to store the values (without any currency signs) - then I don't see why just sending the values as plain numbers from JavaScript won't do job.

So just let your JavaScript be:

```
var total_raw = Number(final_item_total).toFixed(2);

var total_string=total_raw.toString();

var total_show = total_string;
$('#final_total_amt').text(total_show);

$('#me').val(total_show); //displaying on front end textbox
```

That would just send a floating value to the server in the format: `2342.43` - then you wouldn't need to trim any "unwanted values".

Comment: This code works but the reason why I added Intl.NumberFormat converter because the result should be currency format e.g: $2,442.00 or $24,420.00 or $244,200.00 or $2,442,000.00

Comment: @benny then you can do that in the backend using PHP `number_format()`. I think it is best that you do the formatting on the backend because looks like the frontend was giving you problems anyways (hence your question).

Answer (score 0):

You should see where that `Â` comes from, but if you really cannot find it and fix it, as a backup you could use regex to get what you want. A simple example:

```
$str = "Â 2,212.00";
preg_match('/[0-9,.]+/', $str, $final); 
echo $final[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

if that string have fix special character position then you can use this one

$data = explode('Â', 'Â 2,212.00');
echo $data[1];